# Jetty script strange "FIXME" comment

Tags: java, jetty

In /etc/init.d/jetty script, just before the RUN_CMD there is a strange warning:

> # FIXME: Broken solution: wordsplitting, pathname expansion, arbitrary command execution, etc.

Anyone know what is the meaning of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from this commit in 2010 ...

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/1b90cea30ee9329938683ee3bc9f0f945e4a230c#diff-8ebf8c73b1ff1082e3addf005e4d900eR541

... the `RUN_CMD` suffers if there are things like spaces in path names or command line options.

There's been a number of improvements to the subsequent lines since that commit and the concerns are less of a worry anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It was a dev comment added in an old commit ([1b90cea](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/1b90cea30ee9329938683ee3bc9f0f945e4a230c)). It isn't mean as a warning to the user.